# Eclipse program crashing when connecting to MySQL Server

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse-cdt

I am writing a simple program to connect to a MySQL Server hosted locally. I have ensured the server is running. [image: is running] The code I am trying to execute is the following:

```
void CSlaveController::fnDatabaseConnection(){

  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *connection;
  sql::ResultSet *result;
  sql::Statement *statement;
  sql::PreparedStatement *prepared;
  driver = get_driver_instance();

  connection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","DBServer","root"); /*Where the program crashes*/

  statement = connection->createStatement();
  statement->execute("SHOW DATABASES");

  delete statement;
  delete connection;
}
```

One of the issues I have noticed is that the header file **mysql_connection.h** is not found when I run the program. When I build the project, no issue is raised. [image: header after build] But when I run the program, it crashes and this is what I see: [image]. I have double checked the includes and even manually added that specific file. [image]

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? I apologise if there are too many images, I felt that this would be the best way to convey the most information.

Comment: Perhaps tag `c++`?

Comment: Sorry about that. I assumed the **eclipse-cdt** tag would be enough. Added the tag!

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Which MySQL C/C++ connector are you using, did you build it from source or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 160000) // upload file's size up to 16MB /
                                            // 16000000 byte
public class FileUploadToDataBaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /*
     * FileUploadToDataBaseServlet:  files upload to database with Servlet, JSP
     * and MySQL. Creating MySQL database table. Coding upload form page. Coding
     * file upload servlet. Coding message page. Testing the application and
     * verifying file stored in database.
     */
    
    private String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase";
    private String databaseUser = "root";
    private String databasePassWord = "2888";

    /*
     * This method is called by servlet service method to handle the POST
     * request from client. The HTTP POST method allows the client to send data
     * of unlimited length to the Web server a single time and is useful when
     * posting information to the server.
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets values of text fields
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String photo = request.getParameter("photo");

        // InputStream's are used for reading byte based data
        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request

        Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

        Connection connection = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null; // message will be sent back to client

        try {
            // connects to the database
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, databaseUser, databasePassWord);

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO registration (first_name, last_name, phone, email, country, photo )"
                    + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // The performance of the application will be faster if you use
            // PreparedStatement,
            // which gives better performance than Statement class.

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, firstName);
            statement.setString(2, lastName);
            statement.setString(3, phone);
            statement.setString(4, email);
            statement.setString(5, country);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                // bring input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBlob(6, inputStream);
            }

            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            }
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            message = "ERROR: " + exception.getMessage();
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards message to the page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Alert.html").forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).