# Eclipse CDT - Unable to find header files

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I realise this has been asked quite a few times before, but most of those questions dealt with people who were unaware of adding the include paths to `Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Include`.

I am trying to add a few header files related to MySQL to Eclipse and have added them to the above path as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCwlt.jpg) (third on the list). After building the project, [no error is raised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu0hX.jpg) indicating an issue in finding the header.

But on running the application, the ["No such File or Directory"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t4Gz.jpg) error is shown. But what is even weirder is that on asking to [open the Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urWi4.jpg) it leads me to [the right file!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvQnq.jpg)

There are other weird errors like undefined reference errors in the API header files, but I plan on tackling this one issue at a time. I had [posted a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436472/eclipse-program-crashing-when-connecting-to-mysql-server) to which I got no help, so any input, in either case, would be helpful.

EDIT:

These are the build steps where the required files are included:

```
g++ "-IC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector.C++ 1.1\\include" "-IC:\\MinGW\\include" "-IC:\\boost_1_66_0" -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -c -fmessage-length=0 -o CDevice.o "..\\CDevice.cpp" 
In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/connection.h:33:0,
             from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/driver.h:30,
             from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/mysql_driver.h:32,
             from ..\CSlaveController.h:25,
             from ..\CDevice.h:12,
             from ..\CDevice.cpp:8:

g++ "-LC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector.C++ 1.1\\lib\\opt" "-LC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\lib" "-LC:\\MinGW\\lib" -o SlaveController.exe CDevice.o CSlaveController.o main.o "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector.C++ 1.1\\lib\\opt\\mysqlcppconn-static.lib" "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\lib\\libmysql.lib" -lwsock32 -llibmysql -llibmysql -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlcppconn-static
```

The error is:

```
fatal error: mysql_driver.h: No such file or directory  CSlaveController.h  /SlaveController    line 25 C/C++ Problem
```

EDIT 2:

This is the code I am having issues with:

```
sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *connection;
sql::Statement *statement;
sql::PreparedStatement *prepared;
driver = get_driver_instance();

sql::SQLString ip = "127.0.0.1";
sql::SQLString user = "DBServer";
sql::SQLString password = "root";

if(driver !=NULL){
    connection = driver->connect("127.0.0.1","DBServer","root");  //CRASH!!!!
}
```

Comment: It sounds like Eclipse can resolve the include, but your compiler can't (usually people have the opposite problem). Can you give some details about what compiler you're using, what kind of project you have (e.g. makefile vs. managed build), and how you are invoking the build (from Eclipse vs. command line)?

Comment: @HighCommander4 I am using MinGW GCC as my compiler. I am not writing a separate makefile, so I would have to guess that it is a managed build (I apologise for not knowing the exact answer). Also I am invoking the build from Eclipse itself. [This image](https://imgur.com/a/a0IdC) shows the exact build steps, if that is helpful at all. `EDIT`: I moved all the libraries and headers into the workspace, that would be reason for the change in include paths

Comment: I don't see any errors in that screenshot, only warnings. Do you mean that you fixed your problem by moving the headers into the workspace?

Comment: Since adding the extra include paths have you forced a rebuild of the indexer (right-click the project to get pop-up menu then navigate Index->Rebuild)?

Comment: @user4581301: OP is having problems with compiler errors, not eclipse/indexer errors (I know, it's usually the other way around)

Comment: @HighCommander4 It does fix the issue, but it doesn't feel like a final solution. Shouldn't I be able to add headers from any directory? Also, even when the files were not in the workspace there were no build errors (the screenshot I added last was the build output), the errors came only when running. `P.S.`: A few of those warnings were in the header files in the API, is that common for an API released by a company like Oracle?

Comment: My apologies. I read "running the application" to mean the program had been compiled, which flies in the face of the later mention of linker errors. Are the include paths added for one build configuration while compiling for another configuration?

Comment: @user4581301 I have tried forcing the rebuild, but no luck there either. Like I said in my previous reply, moving the files into my workspace does fix this issue but it feels like a dependency I should not have. `EDIT`: I have just one build configuration (Debug)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say there are no build errors and you only get an error when running the application, but the error your screenshot shows (`"fatal error: mysql.h: no such file or directory"`) is a build error.

Comment: You are correct. You should not have to do this. Can you copy the build command line from the console output tab and add it to the question along with a copy of the full error message? There may be some extra information   in either that can be used to help.

Comment: @HighCommander4 I am really sorry for the confusion. [This is the state after build](https://imgur.com/a/wGE0c). As you can see the build has finished and no visible errors. [This is after I run the built application] (https://imgur.com/a/CpQKI)

Comment: Please stop with the images and paste in the text. We can usually get more out of a complete text crawl than we can out of chopped-up bits of your screen.

Comment: Are you sure the build finishes successfully? "Build Finished" does not necessarily mean "finished without errors". Can you please post the entire contents of the Console view after a build into a site like pastebin.com (like @user4581301 said, **text**, not an image) and post the link here?

Comment: @HighCommander4 https://pastebin.com/8dut81u9  Will this do? I just copied the entire build output.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry about the images. I thought it would be more useful to show what was exactly happening on my screen. I have added the edits and have also included a pastebin link with the entire build output in my previous comment to HighCommander4

Comment: Ok, here's what I see in the build output: 1) the compiler commands that are being run contain the relevant include paths, like `C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\include` 2) accordingly, the build succeeds without errors. I don't know why build errors later show up in the Eclipse UI. Do they actually prevent you from running/using your program?

Comment: @HighCommander4 The main issue I am facing is that my application crashes when I try to connect to a locally hosted MySQL server (using the MySQL API). I have added the code I am trying to run above. If I comment out the `driver->connect()` line my application runs fine even with this header issue. I am trying to put out these fires one by one in the hope that they solve my main issue. Thanks for taking the time to help though!! :)

Comment: Ok - the crash (a runtime error) is unrelated to the "fatal error: no such file or directory" (a build error, though it seems to be a bogus one in this case since your build succeeds). I suggest posting a new question for your crash, called something like "Crash when trying to make connection to MySQL database".

Comment: "In file included from ..." there should be an error message at the end. Eg: `In file included from ../src/example.cpp:1:0: <eol> ../src/a.h:12:10: fatal error: b.h: No such file or directory`. The posted error looks like a copy/paste from the problems tab. If it's on the problems tab and not in the build output, it's Eclipse's CODAN tool misconfigured or making a mistake. On the crash, Use Eclipse's debugger, place a breakpoint on `if(driver !=NULL){` and make sure that driver is not only not NULL, but also pointing to a valid instance.